# Second iteration doesn't work

Tags: python

The question I had to answer was:

> Implement a function with signature
>
> ```
> def expand_one_or(course_lists):
> ```
>
> This function takes a list of lists of strings course_lists, and
>   modifies it as follows:
>
> - It finds the first list (call it lis) in course_lists in which "/" occurs.
> - It then finds the coordinate of the first "/" in lis (say i).
> - If lis[i-1] and lis[i+1] exist and are both courses, lis is replaced in course_lists with two new lists: a list identical to lis but with
>     lis[i] and lis[i+1] removed, and a list identical to lis but with
>     lis[i] and lis[i-1] removed.
> - Otherwise, all that happens is that lis[i] is removed from lis.
>
> For example, if course_lists is:
>
> ```
> [ ["CSC148H1", "/", "CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/",
> "CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
> ```
>
> expand_one_or finds the first "/", and modifies course_lists to become
>
> ```
> [ ["CSC148H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"],
> ["CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
> ```
>
> And if we run expand_one_or a second time on the resulting list, we
>   get
>
> ```
> [ ["CSC148H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"],
> ["CSC148H1", ",", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"]
> ["CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
> ```

The code I used to do this was:

```
c = [ ["CSC148H1", "/", "CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/",
"CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
d = [['CSC148H1', ',', 'CSC165H1', '/', 'CSC240H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/'], ['CSC150H1', ',', 'CSC165H1', '/', 'CSC240H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/']]
def expand_one_or(course_lists):
    accumulator = []
    k = 0
    for lis in course_lists:
        for i in range(len(lis)):
            if lis[i] == '/' and i != len(lis) and k == 0:
                if lis[i - 1].isalnum() and lis[i + 1].isalnum():
                    k = 1
                    list1 = lis[:i] + lis[(i + 2):]
                    list2 = lis[i + 1:]
                    accumulator.append(list1)
                    accumulator.append(list2)

                else:
                    lis.remove(lis[i])
                    k = 1
    return accumulator
```

This code functions for the first iteration but doesn't work for the second one.

So for example if we give the function a list like:

```
[ ["CSC148H1", "/", "CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/",
"CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
```

it should give the output

```
[['CSC148H1', ',', 'CSC165H1', '/', 'CSC240H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/'], ['CSC150H1', ',', 'CSC165H1', '/', 'CSC240H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/']]
```

Now if we put this output code in the function again it should give:

```
[ ["CSC148H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"],
["CSC148H1", ",", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"]
["CSC150H1", ",", "CSC165H1", "/", "CSC240H1", "/", "CSC148H1", ";", "/"] ]
```

The problem is when I run the function for the first time it gives me the proper output. However when I run it for the second time it gives me:

```
[['CSC148H1', ',', 'CSC165H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/'], ['CSC240H1', '/', 'CSC148H1', ';', '/']]
```

And this is the wrong output.

Comment: Can you post sample output? What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work". There are a lot of problems with your implementation. For example, it doesn't exit after breaking up the first line it finds (which is probably why it fails the second time). Also i in the inner loop will never equal len(lis)

Comment: "This code functions for the first iteration but doesn't work for the second one.". Iteration of which loop? what is the course_lists when this happens?

Comment: wait ill edit the entire question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def split_list(l, i):
  return [l[:i] + l[i+2:], l[:i-1] + l[i+1:]]

def expand_one_or(course_lists):
  k = 0
  accumulator = []
  for lis in course_lists:
    if k == 0 and '/' in lis:
      k = 1
      i = lis.index('/')
      if i > 0 and i < len(lis)-1 and lis[i-1].isalnum() and lis[i+1].isalnum():
        accumulator += split_list(lis, i)
        k = 1
      else:
        accumulator.append(lis[:i] + lis[i+1:])
    else:
      accumulator.append(lis)
  return accumulator
```

Comment: When I try this code it says 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: What input are you using? When I try it with your input it provides the expected output. Are you sure that you are passing a list of lists as the input to `expand_one_or`?